# How to retrieve the controller type in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

I can easily grab the current controller and action method, using the HttpContext `RouteData` property in ASP.NET Core.

```
var routeData = httpContext.GetRouteData();
var controller = routeData.Values["controller"].ToString();
var actionMethod = routeData.Values["action"].ToString();
```

But what if I need to retrieve the Controller `Type` instead of the `string` value in the above example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, you could try to use `ControllerActionDescriptor` to get the  `ControllerTypeInfo` .

More details, you could refer to this codes:

```
            app.Use(async (context, next) => {
                var controllerActionDescriptor = context
   .GetEndpoint()
   .Metadata
   .GetMetadata<ControllerActionDescriptor>();
                //You could get the controller typeinfo and get the controller according to this typeinfo
                var re = controllerActionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo;

                await next();

            });
```

Comment: I'm having issues retrieving an Endpoint from context
   .GetEndpoint() I am using endpoint routing and have tried to move my middleware order in Startup.cs

Comment: In order for GetEndpoint() to return the actual endpoint instad of null, the following conditions have to be met.

Enable endpoint routing (AddControllers() instead of AddMvc())
Call your middleware between UseRouting() and UseEndpoints().